# Why does this class file get created?

Tags: java, class, javac

In Java all classes are loaded into the JVM dynamically, upon the first use of a class.

Does it mean if i have class in a my source file and I do not make any reference to it then its `Class` object is not created (i.e. `.class` file is not created)?

In the sample code below iam not making a refernce to `test3` class but still its class object gets created.

```
class test1 {
    static {
        System.out.println("static block of test1");
    }
}   
class test2{
    static {
        System.out.println("static block of test2");
    }
}
class test3 {}
class MyExample1 {
    public static void main(String ...strings ) {
    new test1();
    new test2();
    }
}
```

Why `test3.class` file gets created?

Comment: "loading a class" is **not** the same as "creating a .class file". The dynamic class loading happens *long after* the compilation step, which creates the .class files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*.class* file was created at *compilation* time. But, it will be loaded from *.class* file by first usage (probably).

From where it should be loaded without *.class* file?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between the **file** `test3.class` (which is created by the compiler) and the **class object** `test3.class` of class `test3`, which is created on runtime when the class is loaded by the classloader.

The **class file** is always created if you compile a `.java` source file (compilation unit) with the class in it (most often `class3.java`, but it can also be named anything else, if the class is not public) - or implicitely if the class is used by another compiled class.

The **class object** is created by the classloader when the class is first loaded - this occurs whenever it is needed, or earlier. The normal `URLClassLoader` loads your class from a file with the same name, but in principle the data could also be generated on the fly, loaded from a database or similar.
It (the class) then is initialized by invoking the `static` blocks. (The initialization is a second step, not necessarily at the same time, but both are before your first use of the class.)